# Is it possible to hide a specific ColumnHeader in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate, controltemplate

I wonder if it is possible to hide a specific Column Header in DataGrid,for example i want to hide the Header of Column 2,because i need to put a Contol inside that ,and don't need the header anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly.
Yes, you can hide it by doing something like:

You can put whatever you want into header of column2, it needs only UIElement as far I know. You can put there calculator etc. Just switch it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply DataGridColumnHeader style

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid  >
                    <!-- Put the code for the controller here -->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

if you don't wish to show the column header, dont include `<ContentPresenter />` tag with in the style